# Populate ListView using custom DataTemplate and dynamic data

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListView that I would like to populate in XAML. I'm using a custom DataTemplate to make each ListViewItem added contain a Label and a TextBlock.

The problem is I need to dynamically populate the text of the TextBlock of each ListViewItem with data from a settings property, and I don't know how to create this binding.

Right now I am populating the ListView with an XmlDataProvider, but I can't (or at least can't figure out how to) bind values to the xml data. (I'm not stuck using this method of data population, it's just what I was originally doing when I ran into this problem.)

Basically I need something as follows:
The user enters some data into a text box. That data is saved to user settings. When that happens, the corresponding TextBlock of the ListViewItem in the ListView is updated with the user setting data.

Normally I would bind a TextBlock's text to a user setting as follows:

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},Path=User_Data_1}"
```

But how do I do this when the text of the TextBlock is defined in the DataTemplate?

**My DataTemplate and XmlDataProvider:**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="listViewTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="{Binding XPath=name}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbValue" Text="{Binding XPath=value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="PagesData" XPath="Pages">
        <x:XData>
            <Pages xmlns="">
                <page id="page01">
                    <name>Text file:</name>
                    <value></value>
                    <source>Pages/Page_CreateFiles1.xaml</source>
                </page>
                <page id="page02">
                    <name>Xml file:</name>
                    <value></value>
                    <source>Pages/Page_CreateFiles2.xaml</source>
                </page>
                <page id="page03">
                    <name>Memory object database:</name>
                    <value></value>
                    <source>Pages/Page_CreateFiles3.xaml</source>
                </page>
                <page id="page04">
                    <name>Output database:</name>
                    <value></value>
                    <source>Pages/Page_CreateDB.xaml</source>
                </page>
            </Pages>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
```

**My ListView**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvNavigation" 
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource listViewTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PagesData}, XPath=page}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model with a collection of items

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
}
```

and set the MainWindow's DataContext to an instance of the view model class

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.Items.Add(new Item { Name = "Name 1", Value = "Value 1" });
    vm.Items.Add(new Item { Name = "Name 2", Value = "Value 2" });
}
```

Bind to it like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That looks like it will work, but I was hoping to be able to do this in XAML. Any ideas? Also, if I were to do it that way, how would I bind to my settings property?

Comment: Not sure what exactly "bind to my settings property" is supposed to mean here. Isn't the question about a collection of items? So you want to bind to multiple settings properties? And isn't there a variable number of items? Otherwise an ItemsControl would make that much sense.

Comment: Ok yeah I guess I wouldn't be binding anymore, since it's not through XAML. I would just set it to the settings property. I just had binding in my head because that's what I'm trying to do, use xaml binding to populate a property of a listviewitem in a listview.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, thank you for the answer, that totally works, great job, I understand what you're proposing...it's just not what I wanted to do hah maybe what I'm trying to do just isn't possible. I don't know, I'll mark your post as the answer in like a day if I don't get any other suggestions.

Comment: Binding to a specific settings property like `User_Data_1` contradicts the concept of a "data template" which is, well, a template for data provided at runtime. You may however populate the Items collection from a set of Settings properties, and of course add, edit and remove items at runtime.

Comment: I don't see how that is contradictory. I used a DataTemplate to tell the ListView to format all ListViewItems with a vertical StackPanel consisting of a Label and a TextBlock, then bind the content/text properties of those controls to something else that will be dynamically changing during runtime, which is why I needed a binding.

Comment: What I mean is that binding to a specific setting isn't dynamic, and you're asking about dynamic data. As a side note, I also don't understand why you're using a Label and a TextBlock. Both show a string, so why not use either two TextBlocks or two Labels? Preferably TextBlocks, Labels are meant to also support non-textual content like icons.

Comment: It is dynamic though because it's going to be changing during runtime with user input. And I'm using a Label and a TexBlock because they have different formatting properties from each other, and when I was designing it I was utilizing them, but took them out here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Clemmens answer is right, but I just wanted to put it out there that I basically did his approach with a slight modification. I used events to trigger the data change in the listview.

I think it is my own fault though, because I didn't explain my problem well enough. First of all, I wanted to do everything from xaml and I don't think that was possible. Second, I failed to mention that I was using pages in a frame, where the data was coming from the pages and the listview was in my main window that contained the frame. So that's why I ended up using events to communicate between the page and the main window.

So in my main window I've defined my observable collection:

```
    ObservableCollection<NavItem> NavItems = new ObservableCollection<NavItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavItems.Add(new NavItem { Name = "Text file:", Value = "", Source = "Pages/Page_CreateFiles.xaml" });
        NavItems.Add(new NavItem { Name = "Xml file:", Value = "", Source = "Pages/Page_CreateFiles.xaml" });
        NavItems.Add(new NavItem { Name = "Memory object db:", Value = "", Source = "Pages/Page_CreateFiles.xaml" });
        NavItems.Add(new NavItem { Name = "Output database:", Value = "", Source = "Pages/Page_CreateDB.xaml" });

        lvNavigation.ItemsSource = NavItems; 

        ...

    }
```

"NavItem" is a class that is subscribed to INotifyPropertyChanged. Posting that code will just be a lot, so check out how to do that here: [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Then in each page I set up an event that I call with the data to send:

```
    public static event EventHandler<NavUpdateMessage> UpdateMessage;

    private void OnUpdateMessage(int id, string message)
    {
        NavUpdateMessage navUpdateMessage = new NavUpdateMessage();
        navUpdateMessage.Id = id;
        navUpdateMessage.Message = message;

        var e = UpdateMessage;

        if (e != null)
            e(this, navUpdateMessage);
    }
```

With the main window subscribed to that event:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ...

        Pages.Page_CreateFiles.UpdateMessage += Pages_UpdateMessage;
        Pages.Page_CreateDB.UpdateMessage += Pages_UpdateMessage;
    }

    private void Pages_UpdateMessage(object sender, NavUpdateMessage e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            NavItems[e.Id].Value = e.Message;
        }));
    }
```

I'm sure there's a better, more simple approach to this, but this is what I could figure out. And even though I'm sure no one will see this because this question definitely did not get any traction, please feel free to suggest a better solution so at least I can learn.